# RichTextBox text is not shown C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

using richtextbox control programatically i'm appending text to the richtextbox .

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("hello");
```

somehow the text appears in the `richTextBox1.Text` but is not shown in the form.
any idea of what might be the problem?
(I checked the forecolor seems ok).
Thanks in advance

***Edit:***
found the root cause (had by mistake the initializeComponent() twice. )

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // richTextBox1
    // 
    this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(114, 104);
    this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
    this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 96);
    this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

   public Form1()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("hello world");
    }`
```

but still curious about why did this cause this weird behavior?

Comment: Well this code should work. Just to be sure, I've just tested it on an empty project... Can you provide more details on your project? Can you narrow the problem to the minimal code in which it still happens and post the code? This may help someone help you.

Comment: Thanks helped me find out the root cause. do you know why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the same happen when you do `richTextBox1.Text = "hello";`?

**EDIT: trying to explain the problem**

Without seeing the entire code it's difficult for me to know for sure.

But my guess is, that something caused your `OnLoad` event handler to be called from within the first call to `InitializeComponent`, and then in the second call the `RichTextBox` was replaced with a new instance, and your text was added to the old instance.

If you post the minimal code that still has behavior (including the content of `InitializeComponent`), I can try help figure out the reason.

**EDIT 2**

Well, when you call `InitializeComponent` twice, you actually create two instances of all the controls on your `Form`. So what happened was, the first call created one `RichTextBox`. Then the second call created another `RichTextBox` in exactly the same location, with the same size. Then you set the text to the second `RichTextBox`.

The reason you can't see the text is because the first `RichTextBox` is *hiding* the second one! To test that, you can add some code to change the location of `richTextBox1` after you set its text, and then you'll see that there are two of them...